# Silently update and install apk without show any prompt from private server

Tags: android

I need to install apk from private server silently without showing any prompt, because i want to test my app in more than 50 devices. So i don't want to install manually in each device.

Comment: do you want to do that programmatically? Or which way?

Comment: programmatically, actually i want to install an apk in my device and it will work as a script.
whenever i boot my device script check is there any update available then script start download an apk from server silently in background and delete previous one.

Comment: it is not possible to install APK programmatically unless your installer APK has root access, is a system app, or is the device admin app.

Comment: I also want to know the way -- then I can hack into user's device without being noticed...

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible unless devices are rooted.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution called MDM(Mobile Device Management) which can actually do this. 
https://gsuite.google.com/products/admin/mobile/